# Sqlite3 editor - viewer

Tags: sqlite3

is there any (free) program for sqlite3 viewer.

I used db browser for sqlite3 but it doesn't have all available sqlite3 data types (datetime,varchar,...)

Comment: [Beekeeper Studio](https://www.beekeeperstudio.io/) is a pretty decent client for all sorts of databases 

Comment: Hm, 2 weeks free only.

Comment: SQLite only supports INTEGER, REAL, TEXT, BLOB, and NULL data types (https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). What do you mean by "doesn't have all available data types"? Do you mean creating a table with an arbitrary data type name or editing a datetime value in a specific editor?